# Share styling react native and react web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, semantic-ui

for react web, I'd like to try semantic-ui (http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage)

for react-native, I don't think there's a framework that can help us with styling. (which is hard to believe, maybe I'm too new to react world)

My question is, Is there a way for us to share styles for the two platforms (web/native) somehow?

Comment: Short answer is that without some small effort no this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

There are external dependencies that could be used as tools to achieve what you are talking about [react-native-css](https://github.com/sabeurthabti/react-native-css) is one option.

Without any external dependencies I think you can still achieve succesfull results... You will just need to export style modules in your react-native app and pass them as props. You can use the [Platform module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-module) (from rn) to conditionally render styles depending on device operating system. Remember, layouts in react native are created with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) so any successful shared styles between web and native would have to be written with that in mind. ([Bootstrap 4 supports flex.](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/))